# Spyder Crash on Startup

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

It looks like an issue with a package for the utils\github.py script at start up.

I've searched around and it looks like people have had similar issues and it may be related to the OpenSSL? I'm not seeing anything exactly like what I am facing, mostly stuff for Python 2, and from a while ago.

I've tried uninstalling everything, including OpenSSL and reinstalling it all. This was literally working fine a few days ago. Not sure what changed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dmcmanu1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3285, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\dmcmanu1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3140, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "C:\Users\dmcmanu1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 809, in setup
    from spyder.plugins.console import Console
  File "C:\Users\dmcmanu1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\console.py", line 37, in <module>
    from spyder.widgets.reporterror import SpyderErrorDialog
  File "C:\Users\dmcmanu1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\reporterror.py", line 26, in <module>
    from spyder.widgets.github.backend import GithubBackend
  File "C:\Users\dmcmanu1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\github\backend.py", line 33, in <module>
    from spyder.utils.external import github
  File "C:\Users\dmcmanu1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\external\github.py", line 58, in <module>
    from urllib.request import build_opener, HTTPSHandler, HTTPError, Request
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler' from 'urllib.request' (C:\Users\dmcmanu1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py)
```

Is it possible to skip this step if this isn't easily remedied?

Comment: ...Found no solution, simply installed Python 2.x and it worked